# Converting swing JTree to javafx TreeView

Tags: swing, javafx, javafx-2, jtree

I am stuck at converting JTree to TreeView.

Basically I am extensively using `TreePath`s and contextmenu and a class `extends` `DefaultMutableTreeNode`

My specific questions are

1. What is the counterpart of `TreeNode`? And does it satisfy all the functionality which is available there.
2. In Swing JTree any children need not have unique parent. But yes, in a parent every child should have unique index. Is it possible in javafx TreeView.
3. Counterpart of `showRootHandles` in TreeView?
4. Replacement for Component `setBounds` method in javafx or to totally ignore it?
5. In my old swing jtree I am adding new Nodes on getting application action event (business logic) and then determining the index through `TreePath`s what would be the corresponding approach in `TreeView`?

**UPDATE 1**

So far what I have done -
I am creating a generic class extending `TreeItem<ProductI>` (ProductI is my domain class) 
Instead of Panel, I have JFXPanel now containg TreeView instead of JTree.

Originally my JTree was making a TreeNode (extending DefaultMutableTreeNode) and passing it tp DefaultTreeModel and then passing it to JTree.

Instead of the TreeSelectionListener

I have this code now

```
myTree.selectedItemProperty().addListener();
```

and a ChangeListener implementing annonymous class in it.

```
myTree though has multiple selection possible through
```

myTree.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE)

I doubt my above new Listener then instead of TreeSelectionListener won't work. I havent tested it so far, can somebody point em to how to listen to multiple selections too in that case.

will this do?

```
myTree.getSelectionModel.getSelectedItems().addListener(.....)
```

how to get last selected item (out of multiples) then?

Comment: what did you try so far and where exactly are you stuck ;-) And seeing some of your sub-questions (first part of 2 and 4) makes me suspect you are doing something weird in Swing. Good luck, though.

Comment: Yeah its a legacy app. So I am not sure may be the swing app was not built with right design. For the other stuff I am updating in the question itself.